# Codeigniter Config Folder

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Is is possible to move config folder on same level of application folder?

I would like to have   a structure like this:

- application

  - controllers
  - models
  - views
- config
- error
- system

Comment: Modify system/core/Loader.php to get this done, but not recommended.

Comment: Can I overwrite Loader.php with MY_Loader.php? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't do it with CodeIgniter's native functions. But You can load them manually if You really want.

At the end of `/application/config/config.php` add "folder scanner" function with `require_once()`. Something like this:

```
foreach(glob(FCPATH.'config/*.php') as $cfg){
    require_once($cfg);
}
```

**upd** Also You can add `FCPATH.'config/'` to CodeIgniter's core (`/system/core/Config.php` at `var $_config_paths = array(APPPATH); // => var $_config_paths = array(APPPATH,FCPATH.'config/');`) but this is bad practice because folder `/system/` updates when CI updates.

**upd2** as @jhuet wrote at the comments below: Instead of hacking right into CI's core classes, you should rather create at class called `MY_Config` in `application/core` directory. Make this class extend `CI_Config` and in the constructor change the value of `$_config_path`

Comment: I just stumbled upon this proposition. Instead of hacking right into CI's core classes, you should rather create at class called `MY_Config` in `application/core` directory. Make this class extend `CI_Config` and in the constructor change the value of `$_config_path`.

Comment: @jhuet yeah, Your comment is absolutely right, I'll update my answer now, thanks! Anyway I stiil don't think that's a good practice to change CI's file structure :)